# Hibernate read properties from JNDI

Tags: hibernate, jndi

We are using Glassfish 4.1.2 and PostgreSQL 9.4. We configured the JDBC Connection Pool and the JDBC Resource as per instructions, but periodically we have an issue where something goes wrong and Glassfish "loses" the Pool. So we've decided to move away from Glassfish managing the connection pool and manage it through Hibernate with HikariCP. So far so good.

Our devops team want to put the database connection details (url, username, password) in our Glassfish JNDI properties. Is it possible to read from here into Hibernate through some clever config, or do I have to write a custom PersistenceProvider?